# How do I overlay an input image with a color when clickin on it?

Tags: html, css, image, input, focus

I can't find a way to make an `<input type="image>` change into a color when the user clicks on it, meaning the space the image was occupying would be replaced by a plain color. My code is the following:

```
    input:focus{
    color:#0C6
}
```

and

```
<input type="image" src="image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a parent wrapper having the desired color,
and on input `:focus` make it transparent using `opacity`

```css
.imageWrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #0C6;
}

.imageWrapper input[type=image]{
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: 0.3s; /* fade nicely :) */
}

.imageWrapper input[type=image]:focus{
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="imageWrapper">
    <input type="image" src="//placehold.it/60x60/f00">
</span>
```